# Detail view data confusing when peek

Tags: swift, master-detail, 3dtouch

Im trying to implement 3D touch support for my app and I'm encountering some issues at the moment

```
//3D Touch - Peek
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {return nil}

        let identifier = "TemplateTestViewController"
        guard let BarVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as?
            TemplateTestViewController else { return nil }

        //Set Ups the Image Template :
        BarVC.HeaderprofileImage?.image = UIImage(named: ProfileImages[indexPath.row] + "jpg")
        //Sets Up Bar Or Club Text :
        BarVC.BarOrClubLabel?.text = ProfileBarOrClub[MyIndex]
        //Sets Up Age Text :
        BarVC.AgeLabel.text = AgeText[MyIndex]
        //Sets Up Phone Number Text :
      BarVC.ProfilePhoneNumberLabel?.setTitle(ProfilePhoneNumbers[indexPath.row], for: .normal)

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        return BarVC
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to change the `data` between each cells with `MyIndex` which is basically `indexPath.row`. I don't get any errors and yet when i run the app the data isn't changed between different cells being peeked...

any help will be really appreciated !

Comment: which line exactly changes data between each cell?

Comment: @iWheelBuy  I'm changing the data by index path with arrays

Comment: var ProfileImages = ["Shalvata cover"]
     var firstOpeningHours = ["","","","","",]

Comment: @iWheelBuy  Do you know how to change the data shown in peek ?